# Where is the source code for the Lodash _.find() function?

Tags: javascript, github, lodash, open-source

[Here is the find function for Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#find).

###### Example

```js
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney',  'age': 36, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'active': true }
];
 
_.find(users, function(o) { return o.age < 40; });
// => object for 'barney'
 
// The `_.matches` iteratee shorthand.
_.find(users, { 'age': 1, 'active': true });
// => object for 'pebbles'
 
// The `_.matchesProperty` iteratee shorthand.
_.find(users, ['active', false]);
// => object for 'fred'
 
// The `_.property` iteratee shorthand.
_.find(users, 'active');
// => object for 'barney
```

[Here is the Lodash Github repo](https://github.com/lodash/lodash).

I'm trying to find the `_.find()` function in the repo but I don't see it.

Where is it?

Comment: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/search?q=_.find

Comment: [The doc](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#find) points to [this line](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.15/lodash.js#L9212) which in turn points to [this line](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.15/lodash.js#L5051).

Comment: To close-voters, remember that "where is authoritative source for X" is not a 'request for off-topic tools or resources'.